# Using lxml.etree with no root/parent element

Tags: python, lxml

I have some SGML that looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE sometype>
<ITEM>
<DATE>19-OCT-1987</DATE>
<TEXT>
<TITLE>I AM THE TITLE</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>I AM THE AUTHOR</AUTHOR>
<DATELINE>WHEN I WAS CREATED</DATELINE><BODY>
I WANT TO PRESERVE THIS TAG!
</BODY></TEXT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>...
```

I tried to parse it with lxml.html, but it appears to strip the BODY tags, which I need to preserve. Next I tried to use lxml.etree, but as you can see there is not common parent element for all the ITEM tags. The code I'm currently using

```
doc = """<!DOCTYPE sometype>
<ITEM>
<DATE>19-OCT-1987</DATE>
<TEXT>
<TITLE>I AM THE TITLE</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>I AM THE AUTHOR</AUTHOR>
<DATELINE>WHEN I WAS CREATED</DATELINE><BODY>
I WANT TO PRESERVE THIS TAG!
</BODY></TEXT>
</ITEM>"""

from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True) # I have invalid HTML chars to ignore
sgml = etree.fromstring(doc, parser)
```

Now sgml is only the first ITEM element. I need it to be all of the ITEM elements. Any ideas? lxml.html does what I want, but it strips the BODY tags by default, and I haven't found a way to disable this behavior.

Comment: Not having a parent element makes the document invalid XML; treating it as HTML is also not correct, since it really isn't HTML either. You'll have to use a SGML parser instead. `lxml` is *not* up to this task because the underlying `libxml2` is not up to the task.

Comment: There is the [`sgmllib` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sgmllib.html) as part of the Python stdlib. Unfortunately, the parser is considered obsolete and no longer available in Python 3, but it may work for your needs here.

Comment: The other alternative is to convert the document to XML; for this you need to have the DTD as well. See [Parse SGML with Open Arbitrary Tags in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12505419).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was worried about. I was hoping to avoid using a deprecated library, but I guess I'll have to for this.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a common parent element? Just make one!
You can just rewrite them to have a parent element, say ROOT. Insert `<ROOT>` before the first `<ITEM>` and `</ROOT>` at the end of the document. It's pretty trivial to do programmatically, even if you have to preserve the actual on-disk content.

eg.

```
<!DOCTYPE sometype>
<ROOT>
<ITEM>
<DATE>19-OCT-1987</DATE>
<TEXT>
<TITLE>I AM THE TITLE</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>I AM THE AUTHOR</AUTHOR>
<DATELINE>WHEN I WAS CREATED</DATELINE><BODY>
I WANT TO PRESERVE THIS TAG!
</BODY></TEXT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<DATE>19-OCT-1879</DATE>
<TEXT>
<TITLE>I AM THE TITLE</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>I AM THE AUTHOR</AUTHOR>
<DATELINE>WHEN I WAS CREATED</DATELINE><BODY>
I WANT TO PRESERVE THIS TAG!
</BODY></TEXT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<DATE>19-OCT-9871</DATE>
<TEXT>
<TITLE>I AM THE TITLE</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>I AM THE AUTHOR</AUTHOR>
<DATELINE>WHEN I WAS CREATED</DATELINE><BODY>
I WANT TO PRESERVE THIS TAG!
</BODY></TEXT>
</ITEM>
</ROOT>
```

I've just tried this and it seems to do what you want. Saved as /tmp/goodfoo and loaded with `lxml.etree.fromstring(allcontent)`; then I accessed the text you say 'want to preserve' like this:  `b.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[-1].getchildren()[-1].text`

(that is, get the first ITEM, get its TEXT element, get the TEXT element's BODY element, and return any text content of the BODY element.)