# How can I set a JTree model using an indentation-based text?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I know that JTree's model can be set using this form in the properties section:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jqE4i6x.png]

It takes the text in the left area and based on indentation, it creates the nodes.

My question is: If I have an indented text like the one in the left (say, in a file)  and I want to pass it as an argument to the model from the code, how can I do it? I guess I could parse it manually, but I see that it can do it from the graphical form so there has to be a method already implemented that I can call, right?

Comment: `but I see that it can do it from the graphical form so there has to be a method already implemented that I can call, right?` That graphical form is IDE dependent. You should never write code dependent on an IDE. What happens when you change an use a different IDE? Parsing the code yourself is the easiest and most portable solution that can be used anywhere.

Comment: @camicr I thought that the graphical form was just calling some swing method under the hood that wasn't IDE-dependant. So There isn't any swing method that takes this kind of input and converts it to nodes then?

Comment: No, in swing there is no such thing, but it should not be difficult to parse indented text into a tree structure, see for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735468/parse-indented-text-tree-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
BasicTreeUI basicTreeUI = (BasicTreeUI) myJTree.getUI();
basicTreeUI.setRightChildIndent(10);
```

If that doesn't work I usually do it like this(But it depends on the look you are going for)

```
// retrieve the HashMap of Default properties.  
UIDefaults uiDefs = UIManager.getDefaults();  
// now replace the one we want to change.  
uiDefs.put("Tree.leftChildIndent" , new Integer( x ) );
```

Comment: And how is this related to the question: how to parse a file into a `TreeModel`, where the tree structure is based on indentation in the file. Since that is what this question is about

Answer (score 0):

You should either (a) implement your own TreeModel (see [oracle tutorial on trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)) or (b) take a source code of your IDE and cut appropriate classes from it.

Comment: So, the possibility of setting the model as an indented text is given by the IDE and not by swing itself?