# Creating a tree/deeply nested dict with lists from an indented text file

Tags: python, json, parsing, data-structures, nested

I want to iterate through a file and put the contents of each line into a deeply nested dict, the structure of which is defined by leading whitespace. This desire is very much like that documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858404/creating-a-tree-deeply-nested-dict-from-an-indented-text-file-in-python). I've solved that but now have the problem of handling the case where repeating keys are overwritten instead of being cast into a list.

Essentially:

```
a:
    b:      c
    d:      e
a:
    b:      c2
    d:      e2
    d:      wrench
```

is cast into `{"a":{"b":"c2","d":"wrench"}}` when it should be cast into

```
{"a":[{"b":"c","d":"e"},{"b":"c2","d":["e2","wrench"]}]}
```

A self-contained example:

```
import json

def jsonify_indented_tree(tree):
    #convert indentet text into json
    parsedJson= {}
    parentStack = [parsedJson]
    for i, line in enumerate(tree):
        data = get_key_value(line)
        if data['key'] in parsedJson.keys(): #if parent key is repeated, then cast value as list entry
            # stuff that doesn't work
#            if isinstance(parsedJson[data['key']],list):
#                parsedJson[data['key']].append(parsedJson[data['key']])
#            else:
#                parsedJson[data['key']]=[parsedJson[data['key']]]
            print('Hey - Make a list now!')
        if data['value']: #process child by adding it to its current parent
            currentParent = parentStack[-1] #.getLastElement()
            currentParent[data['key']] = data['value']
            if i is not len(tree)-1:
                #determine when to switch to next branch
                level_dif = data['level']-get_key_value(tree[i+1])['level'] #peek next line level
                if (level_dif > 0):
                    del parentStack[-level_dif:] #reached leaf, process next branch
        else:
        #group node, push it as the new parent and keep on processing.
            currentParent = parentStack[-1] #.getLastElement()
            currentParent[data['key']] = {}
            newParent = currentParent[data['key']]
            parentStack.append(newParent)
    return parsedJson

def get_key_value(line):
    key = line.split(":")[0].strip()
    value = line.split(":")[1].strip()
    level = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
    return {'key':key,'value':value,'level':level}

def pp_json(json_thing, sort=True, indents=4):
    if type(json_thing) is str:
        print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_thing), sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
    else:
        print(json.dumps(json_thing, sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
    return None

#nested_string=['a:', '\tb:\t\tc', '\td:\t\te', 'a:', '\tb:\t\tc2', '\td:\t\te2']
#nested_string=['w:','\tgeneral:\t\tcase','a:','\tb:\t\tc','\td:\t\te','a:','\tb:\t\tc2','\td:\t\te2']
nested_string=['a:',
 '\tb:\t\tc',
 '\td:\t\te',
 'a:',
 '\tb:\t\tc2',
 '\td:\t\te2',
  '\td:\t\twrench']

pp_json(jsonify_indented_tree(nested_string))
```

Comment: Do you want them to always be a list, or just a dict if there's only one element? Me, I would always do a list and just use `defaultdict`

Comment: the input looks more like a directed multigraph, not tree, while the output is a dict, not json. last element in an array is not called a leaf. you did not specify what should happen for multiple-level indentation, only that 2 levels should form a dict of list of dicts of strings.. could you please try to make your intention (business logic) more clear?

Comment: does the input format have a name/spec somewhere?

Comment: Good points @Aprillion. The output is a dict though something I intend to turn into json. My example is perhaps too short but that's because it referenced this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858404/creating-a-tree-deeply-nested-dict-from-an-indented-text-file-in-python) with the fruit example. If that doesn't clarify things, I can refine the actual data I'm using to make a stronger example

Comment: looks like an answer disappeared, there was a good point that `isinstance(parsedJson[data['key']],list)` should be preceded by `data['key'] in parsedJson` to avoid the `KeyError` exception...

Comment: It seems the trick here would be to add a stack for tracking sibling keys in addition to the `parentStack`. Then, per loop, if a sibling key has been "seen" before, turn its value into a list and append the current value to that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is (logically) a lot more straightforward (though longer):

1. Track the `level` and `key`-`value` pair of each line in your multi-line string
2. Store this data in a `level` keyed dict of lists:
   {`level1`:[`dict1`,`dict2`]}
3. Append only a string representing the key in a *key-only* line: {`level1`:[`dict1`,`dict2`,`"nestKeyA"`]}
4. Since a *key-only* line means the next line is one level deeper, process that on the next level: {`level1`:[`dict1`,`dict2`,`"nestKeyA"`],`level2`:[...]}. The contents of some deeper level `level2` may itself be just another *key-only* line (and the next loop will add a new level `level3` such that it will become {`level1`:[`dict1`,`dict2`,`"nestKeyA"`],`level2`:[`"nestKeyB"`],`level3`:[...]}) or a new dict `dict3` such that {`level1`:[`dict1`,`dict2`,`"nestKeyA"`],`level2`:[`dict3`]
5. Steps 1-4 continue until the current line is indented less than the previous one (signifying a return to some prior scope). This is what the data structure looks like on my example per line iteration.

   ```
   0, {0: []}
   1, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}]}
   2, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, 'a']}
   3, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, 'a'], 1: [{'b': 'c'}]}
   4, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, 'a'], 1: [{'b': 'c'}, {'d': 'e'}]}
   5, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, {'a': {'d': 'e', 'b': 'c'}}, 'a'], 1: []}
   6, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, {'a': {'d': 'e', 'b': 'c'}}, 'a'], 1: [{'b': 'c2'}]}
   7, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, {'a': {'d': 'e', 'b': 'c'}}, 'a'], 1: [{'b': 'c2'}, {'d': 'e2'}]}
   ```

   Then two things need to happen. **1**: the list of dict need to be inspected for containing duplicate keys and any of those duplicated dict's values combined in a list - this will be demonstrated in a moment. **2**: as can be seen between iteration 4 and 5, the list of dicts from the deepest level (here `1`) are combined into one dict... Finally, to demonstrate duplicate handling observe:

   ```
   [7b, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, {'a': {'d': 'e', 'b': 'c'}}, 'a'], 1: [{'b': 'c2'}, {'d': 'e2'}, {'d': 'wrench'}]}]
   [7c, {0: [{'k': 'sds'}, {'a': {'d': 'e', 'b': 'c'}}, {'a': {'d': ['wrench', 'e2'], 'b': 'c2'}}], 1: []}]
   ```

   where `wrench` and `e2` are placed in a list that itself goes into a dict keyed by their original key.
6. Repeat Steps 1-5, hoisting deeper scoped dicts up and onto their parent keys until the current line's scope (level) is reached.
7. Handle termination condition to combine the list of dict on the zeroth level into a dict.

Here's the code:

```
import json

def get_kvl(line):
    key = line.split(":")[0].strip()
    value = line.split(":")[1].strip()
    level = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
    return {'key':key,'value':value,'level':level}

def pp_json(json_thing, sort=True, indents=4):
    if type(json_thing) is str:
        print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_thing), sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
    else:
        print(json.dumps(json_thing, sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
    return None

def jsonify_indented_tree(tree): #convert shitty sgml header into json
    level_map= {0:[]}
    tree_length=len(tree)-1
    for i, line in enumerate(tree):
        data = get_kvl(line)
        if data['level'] not in level_map.keys():
            level_map[data['level']]=[] # initialize
        prior_level=get_kvl(tree[i-1])['level']
        level_dif = data['level']-prior_level # +: line is deeper, -: shallower, 0:same
        if data['value']:
            level_map[data['level']].append({data['key']:data['value']})
        if not data['value'] or i==tree_length:
            if i==tree_length: #end condition
                level_dif = -len(list(level_map.keys()))        
            if level_dif < 0:
                for level in reversed(range(prior_level+level_dif+1,prior_level+1)): # (end, start)
                    #check for duplicate keys in current deepest (child) sibling group,
                    # merge them into a list, put that list in a dict 
                    key_freq={} #track repeated keys
                    for n, dictionary in enumerate(level_map[level]):
                        current_key=list(dictionary.keys())[0]
                        if current_key in list(key_freq.keys()):
                            key_freq[current_key][0]+=1
                            key_freq[current_key][1].append(n)
                        else:
                            key_freq[current_key]=[1,[n]]
                    for k,v in key_freq.items():
                        if v[0]>1: #key is repeated
                            duplicates_list=[]
                            for index in reversed(v[1]): #merge value of key-repeated dicts into list
                                duplicates_list.append(list(level_map[level].pop(index).values())[0])
                            level_map[level].append({k:duplicates_list}) #push that list into a dict on the same stack it came from
                    if i==tree_length and level==0: #end condition
                        #convert list-of-dict into dict
                        parsed_nest={k:v for d in level_map[level] for k,v in d.items()}
                    else:
                        #push current deepest (child) sibling group onto parent key
                        key=level_map[level-1].pop() #string
                        #convert child list-of-dict into dict
                        level_map[level-1].append({key:{k:v for d in level_map[level] for k,v in d.items()}})
                        level_map[level]=[] #reset deeper level
            level_map[data['level']].append(data['key'])
    return parsed_nest

nested_string=['k:\t\tsds', #need a starter key,value pair otherwise this won't work... fortunately I always have one
 'a:',
 '\tb:\t\tc',
 '\td:\t\te',
 'a:',
 '\tb:\t\tc2',
 '\td:\t\te2',
 '\td:\t\twrench']

pp_json(jsonify_indented_tree(nested_string))
```